# Is there a wayAndroid-SQLite: how to use another column in method update

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a simple question about the `update(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs)` method of `SQLiteDatabase` class.

I'd like to use this method for performing a query that updates values of a column with the values of another column.
For instance this query:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=coulmn2
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

I know i can do this with `execSQL` but i'd prefer to use `update` method. Is there a way to achieve my goal? Thank you.

Comment: Use the joins to perform the same, Inner join should be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know i can do this with `execSQL` but i'd prefer to use `update` method. Is there a way to achieve my goal?

`update()` is only good for `columnname=?` updates where `?` will be bound with a literal value.

Just use `execSQL()`. Alternatively you can call [`compileStatement()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29) with your SQL and [`executeUpdateDelete()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#executeUpdateDelete%28%29) on the compiled statement to get the number of rows affected.

Comment: Yes, i know. I was hoping there was some trick. execSql not returns rows affected. It could be a limit.